# Шаблоны в xCode

Tags: шаблоны, xcode, ios, objective-c

Знаю, что код, который используешь очень, часто можно записать в какие-то шаблоны, а потом в нужный момент его выдернуть туда, где он нужен.

Поделитесь статейкой, или расскажите, как сделать это. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/